# Unable to create a constant value of type while editing User in EF with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

While trying to see if a table contains a certain set of values I am getting this error. Below is where the error is being thrown. Does anyone know how to get around this exception and still check my table so I can avoid inserting duplicate rows? Thank you!

```
var qryDepts = from p in AuthContext.Dept_User_Bridge
                           where p.UserID == editedUser.UserID
                           select p;

foreach (var dept in editedUser.DeptIDs)
{
    var deptObj = new Dept_User_Bridge { UserID = editedUser.UserID, DeptID = dept };

    //exception thrown here
    if (!qryDepts.Contains(deptObj))
    {
        AuthContext.Dept_User_Bridge.Add(new Dept_User_Bridge
        {
            DeptID = dept,
            UserID = editedUser.UserID
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `qryDepts`?

Comment: Updated code. it is an Iqueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing is you want to load data into Memory with `ToList()`.

```
var qryDepts = (from p in AuthContext.Dept_User_Bridge
               where p.UserID == editedUser.UserID
               select p).ToList();
```

Then, you could try with `Any()`.

```
if(!qryDepts.Any(x => x.UserID == deptObj.UserID))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!